# rxjs visibilitychange event not firing in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to know when the user changes back to the tab containing my page. I tried the visibllity api, but when switching tabs, my subscription is not fired. There are a number of events I subscribe to, all of them fire except when switching tabs.

Here is the code:

```
private subscribeToActionEvents() {

this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  const actionEventNames = ['mousemove', 'scroll', 'keyup',
        'hidden', 'webkitHidden', 'visibilitychange', 'webkitvisibilitychange', 'msvisibilitychange'];

  const events = actionEventNames.map((eventName) => {
    let el = this._element.nativeElement;
    return Observable.fromEvent(jQuery(el).closest('body'), eventName);
  });

  const allActionEvents$ = Observable.merge(...events);

  this._subscriptions$.push(allActionEvents$.subscribe((event) => {
      this._registerUserActivity();
    })
  );
});
```

}

I even tried attaching to 'html' instead of the 'body' tag, no difference.
Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the listeners to document for visibilitychange to work.
simple example, check console output: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkjqrw